# Where is the React State stored?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React and find the state intriguing.  I have some questions regarding React states.

1. Where is the redux storage stored ?  Is only it in the browser ?  Would it be harden to disk ?
2. What is the lifecycle of the storage ?  With each app begin and closing of the browser ?   Can it live beyond a browser restart ?   Or over a machine reboot ?
3. Can multiple instance of the same browser (eg firefox) access the same state object ?  What about different browser (ff and chrome) ?
4. I understand that the state object is recreated everytime the state is updated.  Would that cause corruptions ?  eg if I use multiple useEffect and they all trigger at the same time.  Are they serialised ?  Do I have to take into programming consideration if they are serialised ?
5. Is the state object accessible by react programs only ?  Could other languages also access the store ?
6. Is redux state a feature solely by react or react is just making use of the browser functionality ?
7. I read somewhere that react redux is superceded by react context.  Does it mean I should move away from redux if I write new programs ?  (btw, I just read about context, not sure how to use it yet)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, react state and redux state are not synonyms. React has a built in mechanism for handling state, and redux is an additional way you can manage global state. Redux is commonly used with react, but you can use react without redux, and you can use redux without react.

> 1, 2, 3, and 5

Redux state is just a variable in javascript memory. Unless you take steps to do extra things with it, it goes away when the browser is closed and is not shared between tabs. If you put it in a global location you could access it via code outside your react code; If you keep it as a local variable, then it can't.

> 4. I understand that the state object is recreated everytime the state is updated. Would that cause corruptions ? eg if I use multiple useEffect and they all trigger at the same time. Are they serialised ? Do I have to take into programming consideration if they are serialised ?

Javascript is single threaded. Only one piece of code will be running at a time, so you'll be doing one update, then doing a second update. As long as your redux reducer is doing what it's supposed to and calculating the new state based on the old state, it is fine to dispatch two actions back to back.

> 6. Is redux state a feature solely by react or react is just making use of the browser functionality ?

Redux does not require react. You can use it on its own, or with other ui libraries.

> 7. I read somewhere that react redux is superceded by react context.

It doesn't supersede redux. Context is a useful tool for getting data from point A to point B inside a react app, but that's all it does.

For simple apps, that might be all you need: use react's built in state, then use context to move it around. But doing this has performance pitfalls and can be tedious, so for more complex apps you may want to use a state management library. Redux is an example of such a library. It's a popular example, but not the only option. There are other libraries you could choose from, or you could build your own.

Comment: 1. How to store it in a global location ?  You mean to write it out into the OS env or a database ?  2. I'm not familiar with the internals of Javascript.  Would one useEffect start and yield along the way giving the 2nd useEffect a chance to run ?   Does it mean a useEffect will always run to completion before another could start ?   Thanks for your reply.  I think I have a better understanding of it but I probably need to read up more.

Comment: `How to store it in a global location ? You mean to write it out into the OS env or a database ?` Whatever you need. Add it to the `window` object, put it into local storage, send it to a server which then puts it into a database... just depends on what you're trying to do. `Would one useEffect start and yield along the way giving the 2nd useEffect a chance to run` They run back to back. The first one runs to completion, then the second one runs to completion. (I'm assuming they're synchronous functions -- if they kick off async stuff, then they can do whatever you write them to do.)